# I'm trying to remove all words that are under 4 characters long from a list but it's not working

Tags: python, list

I have this code that is supposed to remove all words from a list that are under 4 characters long but it just removes some of the words (I'm not sure which) but definitely not all of them:

```py
#load in the words from the original text file
def load_words():
    with open('words_alpha.txt') as word_file:
        valid_words = [word_file.read().split()]

    return valid_words


english_words = load_words()
print("loading...")

print(len(english_words[0]))
#remove words under 4 letters
for word in english_words[0]:
    if len(word) < 4:
        english_words[0].remove(word)

print("done")
print(len(english_words[0]))

#save the remaining words to a new text file
new_words = open("english_words_v3.txt","w")
for word in english_words[0]:
    new_words.write(word)
    new_words.write("\n")

new_words.close()
```

It outputs this:

```
loading...
370103
done
367945
```

In words_alpha.txt there is 67000 words from the English language

Comment: Since dealing with fairly large number of strings, I'd recommend generators instead of lists. And what's with the `valid_words = [word_file.read().split()]` (the unnecessary outer list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate over a copy of `english_words` by taking it's copy using `english_words[0][:]`. Right now you are iterating on the same list you are modifying, which is causing the wierd behaviour. So the for loop will look like

```
for word in english_words[0][:]:
    if len(word) < 4:
        english_words[0].remove(word)
```

Also you can simplify your first for-loop via list-comprehension, and you don't need to wrap `word_file.read().split()` in a list, since it already returns a list

So your code will look like

```
#load in the words from the original text file
def load_words():
    with open('words_alpha.txt') as word_file:
        #No need to wrap this into a list since it already returns a list
        valid_words = word_file.read().split()

    return valid_words

english_words = load_words()

#remove words under 4 letters using list comprehension
english_words = [word for word in english_words if len(word) >= 4]

print("done")
print(len(english_words))

#save the remaining words to a new text file
new_words = open("english_words_v3.txt","w")
for word in english_words:
    new_words.write(word)
    new_words.write("\n")

new_words.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it, and you too have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
print([word for word in english_words[0] if len(word) >= 4])
```

The problem in your script is that you are modifying a list while iterating over it. You could also avoid this problem by instanciating and populating a new list, but list comprehensions are ideal for this kind of situations.